# Missing persisted data with postgres and docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a Docker Compose file set up for a PostgreSQL container with data persistence. The container works fine on my Windows 11 PC, and I can create tables and insert data without any issues. When I stop and start the container, the data is still present as expected. However, if I restart the entire machine, the data seems to be lost, even though the database objects I created are still there. Here's my Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

All the docs say that it should work....